# Possible error in published proof of Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I don't understand the proof of Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein in https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/news_old/monthly544-553.pdf (Section 2, Bernstein's Equivalence Theorem, Page 546.) I seem to have found a counterexample to the assertion that "all sets $X^*$ are normal". Let $X = \emptyset$. Then the normality of $X^*$ is equivalent to $f(Q)\subset Q$. But this can't be true because $Q$ is a subset of the complement of $A''$ and yet $f$ maps to $A''$.  Am I missing something or is the proof just wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) why the writer asserts that "all sets $X^*$  are normal".  That claim is not used later, indeed the author speaks of a "smallest normal subset"  which is never assumed to be empty.

Comment: Thanks @lulu  I've resolved it now.  Actually, the claim is used later -- $N=N^*$.  But the correct claim is "If $N$ is normal, then $N^*$ is normal."  The corrected claim is indeed used.  It's a pretty significant error for a paper that is clearly written with newbies in mind.

Comment: No...$N=N^*$ because $N$ is minimal.

Comment: @lulu Oh, great! Thanks a lot.  I was trying (and failing) to prove that $N=N^*$.  So the fix is just to remove the erroneous claim.  Then it should work fine.  I'm not sure it's a better exposition than the more standard ones you read elsewhere.

Comment: Neither am I. $\quad $

Comment: @lulu  Actually, I still don't get it because the argument that the minimality of $N$ shows $N=N^*$ is only valid if $N^*$ is itself normal, which isn't obvious (to me).  But never mind, it seems like just a clumsy obfuscating rewrite of the most standard proof that you see everywhere else.

Comment: I agree. Sorting out the details is harder than just using one of the standard proofs.

Comment: So now we get the "please avoid extended discussion" warning.  Certainly not the best reading-a-proof experience I've ever had.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed an error here, as observed in the comments: the claim

> all sets $X^*$ are normal

is false, and should be replaced with

> if $X$ is normal then $X^*$ is also normal.

This is indeed true, and from here the proof proceeds without any issues as far as I can tell. Let $N$ be the smallest normal set (whose existence follows from the fact that arbitrary intersections preserve normality). By the definition of normality we have $N\supseteq N^*$. Meanwhile, since $N$ is normaly we have that $N^*$ is normal as well by our corrected claim above. So by minimality of $N$ we have $N=N^*$. And then there's just a bit of set juggling to wrap up.